# Git alias slower than original command

Tags: git

Using git 2.8.0, I defined an alias in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
   st = status
```

I can confirm using `git config --list --show-origin` that I have only one global and one local config file, with alias only defined globally.

Then if I run `GIT_TRACE=1 git st` it takes 7 seconds:

```
17:18:48.934703 git.c:564               trace: exec: 'git-st'
17:18:48.936703 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-st'
17:18:55.734092 git.c:287               trace: alias expansion: st => 'status'
17:18:55.735092 git.c:564               trace: exec: 'git-status'
17:18:55.735092 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-status'
17:18:55.772094 git.c:351               trace: built-in: git 'status'
```

And `GIT_TRACE=1 git status` it is instantaneous:

```
17:19:23.649688 git.c:351               trace: built-in: git 'status'
```

This happens on a windows machine. Any idea what is the underlying issue?

Comment: Maybe try 2.8.1? I just compared with your output and for me it is a matter of milliseconds. Besidest that after alias expansion already the built-in line is written and not two more like in your output.

Answer (score 1):

> This happens on a windows machine. Any idea what is the underlying issue?

Since git command are based upon linux code they are optimized for unix based OS.
When you run it on Windows (especially with the `GIT_TRACE` on) git has to hook and listen for Windows system calls and set up a verbose and debug mode for those system calls and events.

This is why its slow on Windows.

---

Github has took ownership on the git windows client and since version 2 they are improving it constantly.

Read this out (release notes of 2.8):
[Convergence with Git for Windows](https://github.com/blog/2131-git-2-8-has-been-released)

> There has recently been a big push to make Git **feel as comfortable** on Windows as it does on Linux and OS X.
>
> For example, **it is relatively expensive to start processes on Windows**, so many Git commands that were originally written as scripts have been **rewritten in C to make them snappier**.